# Columns HighChart remove spacing for empty data series

Tags: highcharts, lazy-high-charts

Consider the following high chart

[image]

At 15 jun, category II has no data, what if I dont want that spacing left for it, Is there anyway to remove such spaces.

for code reference

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/G5S9L/8/`
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in the API that allows you to do this.  As a *kludgy* workaround you could shift the columns yourself in the onload callback:

```
, function(chart){
    var barLeft = $(chart.series[0].data[1].graphic.element);
    var barRight = $(chart.series[2].data[1].graphic.element);
    barLeft.attr('x',parseInt(barLeft.attr('x')) + parseInt(barLeft.attr('width'))/2);
    barRight.attr('x',parseInt(barRight.attr('x')) - parseInt(barRight.attr('width'))/2);
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5S9L/11/).

Answer (score 2):

This is how `Highcharts` work. It calculates the space for categories, then divide it between series. It doesn't matter if you have data or not, space is given for possible points.